# How do you turn off XAMLX validation VS2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, workflow-foundation-4, xamlx

How do you **disable** validation for the **Workflow Designer** in **VS2013** ?

Looks like you were able to disable validation of the XAMLX designer for VS 2010 https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2537054

Though changing the registry (DisableValidateOnModelItemChanged) as described in the link above , sadly does not do anything.